# Can I install and use Windows Server on a normal PC?

Tags: webserver

Do I need to buy a server for this, or can I use a desktop PC?

I know that obviously a server is made to be a server, but they are very expensive.

Comment: someone made Windows 95 run on a Nintendo 3DS, so your Desktop PC should be able to handle a Server OS ;-). I would suggest to run your server on Hyper-V on a Desktop-PC though. So Desktop-PC, add Hyper-V feature, create a server in Hyper-V and run it there.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can use Windows Server on regular Hardware with the exception of old Editions that were made for Itanium.

Have a look at the regular [system requriements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/system-requirements) and you'll find that it's just the regular listing.

A server is mostly defined by the kind of workload it has. Though there are cases where you might require special hardware that's just not able to be run on consumer grade hardware.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Server is just an Operating System. It can run on a normal desktop PC. In fact, it can run in a Hyper-V simulated environment that runs on your pc too.

The reason why a server and a desktop are different, is because Server hardware is geared towards high performance because a server is not serving just one person, but many. And each person it serves needs a little bit of ram and cpu time.

Keep in mind that on Windows Server, hardware is not supported in the same manner as on Windows 10 out of the box. That said, Windows Server has the same architecture when it comes to Windows for desktops. Windows Server 2016 shares the same core as Windows 10, Windows Server 2012 shares the same core as Windows 8. Windows Server 2008 R2 shares the same core as Windows 7, etc.. If you have drivers for the desktop version, they can usually be used on the Windows Server side too.

In fact I run my virtual environment at home on an Intel NUC pc. It runs Windows Server 2016 Core, and ontop in Hyper-V, 2 servers are virtualized.

Answer (score 2):

Here's first hand experience, not just some theoretical Johnny abusing his internet access. I run Windows Server Datacenter 2022 on my HP Probook G7. It does need some tweaking before installation (mostly services disabling/enabling, shutting down processes, registry additions and such) and a LOT of tweaking after installation so you better have intimate knowledge of Windosw OS. Installing wifi drivers and especially touchpad mouse drivers could be madness if you don't know what to do. Once you get all this behind you get a slim, straightforward and rock-solid OS to run for life. No bloatware, no BS. Most importantly, you don't have to worry about updates because you get only security long term updates (via LTSC channel) without all the trash they try to push in regular windows versions. All programs install and work perfectly - MS Office, Photoshop 2023, CorelDraw latest, Steganos, Acrobat DC and everything in between, no problems whatsoever. Why I did it? First, because I can, Second, due to the stability and reliability of the Server edition. Your milage may vary. Last piece of advice - do not listen to those saying it can't be done. Baby, it can and it's beautiful!